# How To Compare six time on PHP?

Tags: php, time

I have problem with compare 3 Time on PHP.

So the user just input a time now(). but it must have compare with 3 Different time which have been load from database.

the code like this

```
    if(isset($_POST[SUBMIT])) {


        $waktu = strtotime($_POST[WAKTU]); //$waktu variabel input set  hh:mm

     /*Get Time Setting From mysql*/

     $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM promo_time";
     $hasil4 = mysqli_query($sql4);
     $data4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil4);


     $jam1_A = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO1_A]);
     $jam1_B = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO1_B]);

     $jam2_A = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO2_A]);
     $jam2_B = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO2_B]);

     $jam3_A = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO3_A]);
     $jam3_B = strtotime($data4[WAKTU_PROMO3_B]);

if(($waktu >= $jam3_A) || ($waktu <= $jam3_B)){

          if(($waktu >= $jam2_A) || ($waktu <= $jam2_B)) {

               if(($waktu >= $jam1_A) || ($waktu <= $jam1_B)) {


                  echo "Success";


               }
               else {

                   echo "erro 3";   

                }


          }
          else {

            echo "Error 2";  
          }


     }//endif
     else {

         echo "Error 1";     

     }




    }
```

The code result always show "Succes" if I use OR Operator.
But if I user AND operator the code result is always Error 1.

The Preview Like this
[image]

If I input 16:00 the result is success, but if I input 19:00 it still success.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Make an example and show what the expected behaviour would be

Comment: Sample The Time from database time 1 : 02:00 - 05:00 time 2 : 14:00 - 16:00 time 3 : 20:00 - 22:00 and input user 03:00 the result must be Succes, but if user not between one of the time, the result will be error

Comment: Are you need just `is input time in one of database time periods?`?

Comment: `a >= 1 || a <= 2` is true for all numeric a. Use `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a >= 1 || a <= 2` is true for all numeric a. Use `&&`

Like this:

```
$in1 = $waktu >= $jam1_A && $waktu <= $jam1_B;  
$in2 = $waktu >= $jam2_A && $waktu <= $jam2_B;
$in3 = $waktu >= $jam3_A && $waktu <= $jam3_B;
$result = ($in1 || $in2 || $in3) ? 'Success' : 'Error';
echo $result;
```

Comment: I have Try Your suggest but still Error Result.

Comment: double check values of your variables. Ths logic should be correct.

Comment: is  still must Use strtotime?

Comment: It depends) you can also compare datetimes as strings if they are in `2015-06-04 12:00` format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. this work,My error it because the strtotime trouble. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to vp_arth. This should be the correct logic

```
$jam1_bool = $waktu > $jam1_A && $waktu < $jam1_B;
$jam2_bool = $waktu > $jam2_A && $waktu < $jam2_B;
$jam3_bool = $waktu > $jam3_A && $waktu < $jam3_B;

if (!$jam1_bool)
    echo "Error 1";
if (!$jam2_bool)
    echo "Error 2";
if (!$jam3_bool)
    echo "Error 3";
if($jam1_bool && $jam2_bool && $jam3_bool)
    echo "Success";
```

Comment: I have Try your sugestion before i ask on stack overflow. if i use that, the result always show error 1.

Comment: @vp_arth I failed to see how?

Comment: if first condition fails - all fails. Need apply `or` between. Or `elseif`.

Comment: And now you can get `Error 1Error 2Success` result. I think there is only one error - when all period fails. And 3 type of success..

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. For example, if current time is 16:00

```
(16:00>=01:00) || (16:00<=04:14) is true, because (16:00>=01:00) is true

(16:00>=07:12) || (16:00<=10:12) is true, because (16:00>=07:12) is true

(16:00>=15:10) || (16:00<=18:11) is true, because (16:00>=15:10) is true
```

In this case, you will get a "success". As for 19:00

```
(19:00>=01:00) || (19:00<=04:14) is true, because (19:00>=01:00) is true

(19:00>=07:12) || (19:00<=10:12) is true, because (19:00>=07:12) is true

(19:00>=15:10) || (19:00<=18:11) is true, because (19:00>=15:10) is true
```

As a result, it should be "success".

I guess what you want to accomplish is something like:

```
$boo1 = (($waktu >= $jam1_A) || ($waktu <= $jam1_B));
$boo2 = (($waktu >= $jam2_A) || ($waktu <= $jam2_B));
$boo3 = (($waktu >= $jam3_A) || ($waktu <= $jam3_B));
$boo12= (($boo1)&&($boo2));
$boo23= ($boo2)&&($boo3));
$boo13= (($boo1)&&($boo3));
$booAll = ($boo1)&&($boo2)&&(boo3);

if(booALL)
  echo "success"
else if (($boo23==true)&&($boo1==false))
  echo "error 1";
else if (($boo13==true)&&($boo2==false))
  echo "error 2";
else if (($boo12==true)&&($boo3==false))
  echo "error 3";
else
  echo "other errors"
```

Other errors is like when $boo1=true, $boo2=false, $boo3=false. That means the current time is either not in jam2A~jam2B not jam 3A~jam3B, you should also consider this error as error 4, there should be 7 types of errors(including an all-wrong error) totally.